# Xpath - How to get the text of next line at same level java

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to get the text (`Bulk Template`) after the `text()='Template: '`.

```
<div class="description secondary-text">
    <strong data-issue-type-field="name">Template: </strong>
    <span class="description secondary-text">Bulk Template</span>
    <strong data-issue-type-field="name">Save Locally: </strong>
    <span class="description secondary-text">c:\</span>
</div>
```

I've tried with this XPath expression:

```xml
//strong[@data-issue-type-field][text()='Template: ']/../span
```

but it retrieved *two* results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "next" element at the "same level" in XPath world is called [following-sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) therefore the XPath expression you're looking for is:

```
//strong[contains(text(),'Template')]/following-sibling::span
```

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: To be unique, we should put the index. But it works. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Select the first matching element:

```xml
//strong[@data-issue-type-field][text()='Template: ']/../span[1]
```

Comment: Doesn't work, try with the other word: "Save Locally: " and the result is not the next element.

Comment: Of course, for a different problem a different solution might be necessary. This approach only works if the `span` you are looking for is the *first*. Use any of the other approaches.